# C++ one or more multiply defined symbols found

Tags: c++

I have the following struct to manage Camera State with

```
 struct keyState
 {
    float x_rotation, y_rotation, z_rotation;
    float x_rotation_rad, y_rotation_rad, z_rotation_rad;
    float x_pos, y_pos, z_pos;
 } state_manager;
```

This struct is located in my WalkingCameraManipulator.h class. WalkingCameraManipulator is implemented in WalkingCameraManipulator.cpp, and I have an #include "WalkingCameraManipulator" in my main class.

**Error 1 error LNK2005: "struct keyState state_manager" (?state_manager@@3UkeyState@@A) already defined in main.obj
Error   2   error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found**

However, I am dealing with the following error message and need to find the best place for my struct. Any ideas on what I can do here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trailing `state_manager` defines an instance. In a header. Which is wrong. I suggest you refactor your code as:

```
struct keyState
 {
    float x_rotation, y_rotation, z_rotation;
    float x_rotation_rad, y_rotation_rad, z_rotation_rad;
    float x_pos, y_pos, z_pos;
 } ;

extern keyState state_manager;

//somecppfile.cpp
keyState state_manager;
```

The `extern` part is a declaration, and the definition is now in a single implementation file. This mimics your intended behavior, **but** is probably not what you really want. Do you **really** want a global instance of `keyState`? If not, remove it alltogether:

```
struct keyState
 {
    float x_rotation, y_rotation, z_rotation;
    float x_rotation_rad, y_rotation_rad, z_rotation_rad;
    float x_pos, y_pos, z_pos;
 } ;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for clearly explaining that. I had thought that was the C way of declaring a struct type.

Comment: @Kobojunkie no, the C way would be providing a name via a `typedef` - `typedef struct X {} X;`